# GrapesJS - I can't load saved template from database

Tags: javascript, php, json, grapesjs

I am currently working on a **HTML/PHP/JS** application where I am integrating a GrapesJS editor instance. My instance is displaying very well, adding blocks as well and saving to a **MySQL database (JSON format + inlined-html)**.

When I want to access the template corresponding to the identifier saved in the database, I can't load the elements saved, in the editor. On top of that, I get a JSON syntax error on the **backbone.js** file.

How can I display my template in my editor?

**Instance GrapesJS + save command :**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var id = document.getElementById('message').value;
    var listeid = document.getElementById('liste').value;

    var editor = grapesjs.init({
        container: "#editor",
        showOffsets: 1,
        fromElement: true,
        height: '100%',
        noticeOnUnload: 0,
        allowScripts: 1,
        autosave: false,
        autoload: 1,
        storageManager: {
            type: 'remote',
            contentTypeJson: true,
            id: 'gjs-',
            autosave: false,
            autoload: true,
            urlStore: '/app/controller/grapesjs_save.php?id=' + id, //POST
            urlLoad: '/app/controller/grapesjs_load.php?id=' + id, //GET
            contentTypeJson: true,
            storeComponents: true,
            storeStyles: true,
            storeHtml: true,
            storeCss: true,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        },
        selectorManager: {
            componentFirst: true
        },
        plugins: ['grapesjs-component-code-editor', 'grapesjs-parser-postcss', 'grapesjs-preset-newsletter',
            'grapesjs-component-countdown', 'grapesjs-custom-code', 'grapesjs-plugin-export'
        ],
        pluginsOpts: {
            'grapesjs-preset-newsletter': {
                modalTitleImport: 'Importer votre template',
                modalTitleExport: 'Exporter le template',
            },
            'grapesjs-custom-code': {
                blockLabel: 'Code personnalisé',
            },
            'grapesjs-component-code-editor': {
                htmlBtnText: 'Appliquer',
                cssBtnText: 'Appliquer',
                cleanCssBtnText: 'Supprimer',
            },
        },
    });

    /** Ajout de la commande de sauvegarde dans la DB **/
    editor.Commands.add('save-db', {
        run: function(editor, sender) {
            sender && sender.set('active', 0); // turn off the button
            editor.store();
            //storing values to variables
            var htmldata = editor.getHtml();
            var cssdata = editor.getCss();
            var htmlWithCss = editor.runCommand('gjs-get-inlined-html');
            var json = JSON.stringify(editor.getComponents());
            console.log('Complete JSON:', json);
            $.post("/app/controller/grapesjs_save.php", {
                //you can get value in post by calling this name
                "id": id,
                "listeid": listeid,
                "htmlWithCss": htmlWithCss,
                "json": json,
                success: function() {
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: "Email enregistré !",
                        icon: 'success',
                        html: "<a href='/app/message.php?test=" + id +
                            "' class='btn btn-sm btn-block btn-primary'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> Tester le rendu</a>" +
                            "<a href='/app/sending.php?mailid=" + id + "&listeid=" +
                            listeid +
                            "#man' class='btn btn-sm btn-block btn-primary'><i class='fa fa-calendar'></i> Programmer un envoi manuel</a>" +
                            "<a href='/app/sending.php?mailid=" + id + "&listeid=" +
                            listeid +
                            "#auto' class='btn btn-sm btn-block btn-primary'><i class='fa fa-calendar'></i> Programmer un envoi automatique</a>",
                        type: "success",
                        showCancelButton: true
                    });

                },
            });
        editor.on('storage:store', function(e) { console.log('Stored ', e);});  
        },
    });
```

**GrapesJS save url :**

```html
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if (!empty($_POST['id'])) {
    /* Requête ajout template */
    if (isset($_POST['htmlWithCss'])) {
        $msghtml = $_POST['htmlWithCss'];
        $templatedata = $_POST['json'];
        $insert_mess = $db->prepare('UPDATE _mails SET msghtml = :msghtml, templatedata = :templatedata, date_modif = NOW(), ver = 3, type = "auto" WHERE id = :id AND membreid = :membreid');
        $insert_mess->bindValue(':msghtml', $msghtml);
        $insert_mess->bindValue(':templatedata', $templatedata);
        $insert_mess->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $insert_mess->bindValue(':membreid', $user->getId(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $insert_mess->execute();

        $last_id = $db->lastInsertId();

        $sensitiveCount = preg_match_all('/labanquepostale|espace client|identifiant|crypto|investissement/i', $msghtml, $sensitiveMatches);
        if(!empty($sensitiveCount)) {
            trigger_error(print_r(['sensitive matches' => $sensitiveMatches], true));
            SendingProcess::sendMessage('Nouveau message sensible.', '<pre><code>' . print_r(['sensitive matches' => $sensitiveMatches, 'mail' => $last_id, 'user' => $user->getId()], true) . '</code></pre><a href="http://sg-autorepondeur.com/admin_v2/impersonate.php?user-id="'.$user->getId().'" target="_blank">Accéder au compte</a>', 'fabien@haisoft.net', 'Phishing');
        }
    }

}
```

**GrapesJS load url :**

```html
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $select_mess = $db->prepare('SELECT msghtml, build, templatedata FROM _mails WHERE id = :id AND membreid = :membreid');
    $select_mess->bindValue(':id', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $select_mess->bindValue(':membreid', $user->getId(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $content="";
    while($row = $select_mess->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $content = $row['msghtml'];
        $content = $row['build'];
        $content = $row['templatedata'];
    }
    
    //echo json_encode();
    echo $content; 
}
```

[Backbone.js syntax JSON error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNf4p.png)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please update your question and insert all code into code snippets. This allows others to edit and find your question more easily using the search function